# How to map Visual Studio shortcut keys in Github Atom

Tags: visual-studio, coffeescript, atom-editor

How to map the shortcut keys in GitHub Atom just like Visual Studio.

If anyone have keymap file kindly share.

I tried to implement (Ctrl+K ,Ctrl+C) in github atom for comment. It didnt work.
Also Ctrl-K,Ctrl-U to turn off comment

```
    'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-k+ctrl-c': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the *Settings* panel by pressing `ctrl-,` on windows `cmd-,` on mac and select the *Keybindings* tab. It will show you all the keybindings currently in use.

You can also open the keybinding resolver using `ctrl-.` and press `ctrl-k` and see what keybinding it displays.

To assign custom keybindings, go to `File -> Open Your Keymap`. It will open `keymap.cson` file.

Add the following to the `keymap.cson` file.

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-k ctrl-c': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
```

Now you can use `'ctrl-k ctrl-c'` to comment/uncomment your code.

Comment: is there any way to uncomment in github ? with another key shortcut

Comment: You can use the same keyboard shortcut to uncomment your code.